# Iteration over a collection of data in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have been trying to iterate a collection of data in React. It does not give me any error in console but it says

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

Index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

var items = [
    { name: 'Matthew', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mat.1' },
    { name: 'Mark', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mrk.1' },
    { name: 'Luke', link: 'https://bible.com/1/luk.1' },
    { name: 'John', link: 'https://bible.com/1/jhn.1' }
];

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    };

    render(){

        var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <li key={item.name}>
                    <a className='button' href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

render(<Home />,document.getElementById('contain'));
```

I do not understand how to resolve it. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Code looks good. I would suspect that there is something wrong with webpack if You use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get any output because the state `items` is `empty`, You need to either initialise state to `items` or iterate over  the variable `items`

```
var items = [
    { name: 'Matthew', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mat.1' },
    { name: 'Mark', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mrk.1' },
    { name: 'Luke', link: 'https://bible.com/1/luk.1' },
    { name: 'John', link: 'https://bible.com/1/jhn.1' }
];

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: items
        };
    };

    render(){

        var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <li key={item.name}>
                    <a className='button' href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

render(<Home />,document.getElementById('contain'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **state** is empty. You're trying to `map` through empty state.

You should initialise the state as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: items
    };
};
```

Or in lifecycle method as follows:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({items: items})
}
```

Or you should `map` through `items` as follows:

```
var listItems = items.map(function(item) {
                return (
                    <li key={item.name}>
                        <a className='button' href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
                    </li>
                );
});
```

Your code should look like this (initialising state with lifecycle method):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

    var items = [
        { name: 'Matthew', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mat.1' },
        { name: 'Mark', link: 'https://bible.com/1/mrk.1' },
        { name: 'Luke', link: 'https://bible.com/1/luk.1' },
        { name: 'John', link: 'https://bible.com/1/jhn.1' }
    ];

    class Home extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                items: []
            };
        };

        componentWillMount(){
            this.setState({items: items})
        }

        render(){

            var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
                return (
                    <li key={item.name}>
                        <a className='button' href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
                    </li>
                );
            });

            return (
                <ul>
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
            );
        }
    }

    render(<Home />,document.getElementById('contain'));
```